# Magento Upgrade issue. Gomage Light checkout not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6, gomage

I have upgraded my magento system from the version 1.6 to 1.9.0.1. And I have installed the Gomage lightcheckout extension.But the extension is not working with the link "www.example.com/checkout/onepage" but working with "www/example.com/gomage_checkout/onepage".
I want the extension should work with the default checkout link. Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: For this you have to change your module's frontname in that module's configuration file. share your code here. You can find that file in app/code/community or local/Packagename (Gomage)/Modulename (checkout)/etc/config.xml. I'm not sure about the Packagename and Modulename.